# Magento 2: Hook into price display on category page

Tags: magento2, category, layout, price, magento-2.0

I want to add custom notices directly behind every price on product detail and category pages. On product detail page this works fine with layout.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
    <block before="product.info.stock.sku" after="product.price.final" class="..." name="after_price" as="after.price" template="..."/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But actually that doesn't work for category pages. If I look into `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` which is the block on the category page, there is a function called `getProductPrice()` which is called for price rendering. Internally it calls `getPriceRender()` which calls a block from layout which renders the price:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
```

So I thought I just create a `catalog_category_view.xml` layout file with the following content:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">
    <block class="..." before="category.product.type.details.renderers" template="..."/>
</referenceBlock>
```

But unfortunately this is not the solution, it doesn't work. I thought the reason is that `product.price.render.default` is added dynamically as it only can be found on product detail page's layout xml files and not category layout files. But I can't find where it is added. And why does my layout file not work?
I don't want to overwrite the template `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml` as different themes will overwrite my changes.

Comment: what is the problem behind override template files? This is possible using override template files from core

Comment: When you use a theme the template gets overridden again and my changes are lost.

Comment: Perhaps try using a custom Renderer to avoid any .phtml changes? http://blog.belvg.com/renderer-in-magento-2-0.html